# Ensure IO computations are run in a specific thread

Tags: haskell

I need to make sure that some actions are run on a specific OS thread. I wrote an API where this thread runs a loop listening to a `TQueue` and executes the given commands. From the API user side, there is an opaque value that is really just a newtype over this queue.

One problem is that what I really need is to embed arbitrary actions (type `IO a`), but I believe I can't directly exchange messages of that type. So I currently have something like this (pseudo code) :

```
makeSafe :: RubyInterpreter -> IO a -> IO (Either RubyError a)
makeSafe (RubyInterpreter q) a = do
    mv <- newEmptyTMVarIO
    -- embedded is of type IO (), letting me send this in my queue
    let embedded = handleErrors a >>= atomically . putTMVar mv
    atomically (writeTQueue q (SomeMessage embedded))
    atomically (readTMVar mv)
```

(for more details, this is for the [hruby](https://github.com/bartavelle/hruby/) package)

edit - clarifications :

- Being able to send actions of type `IO a` would be nicer, but is not my main objective.
- My main problem is that you can shoot yourself in the foot with this API, for example if there is a `makeSafe` call in the IO action that is passed as a parameter, this will hang.
- My secondary problem is that this solution feels a bit contrived, and I wondered if there was a nicer/safer solution around.

Comment: I don't understand your question (sorry), but if I ignore it and just look at the title, I'm tempted to point you to [`forkOS`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkOS).

Comment: So your problem is passing IO actions with arbitrary return types?

Comment: I already use `forkOS`, as that's the only way to ensure that the ruby interpreter will work at all.

Comment: @bartavelle Why would recursive calles to makeSafe hang, btw?

Comment: On the other side of the `TQueue`, you have a loop that reads a single message, process it, and returns. It can't process two messages at the same time (that's the goal here). And `makeSafe` is basically just pushing a message and waiting for it to be processed, so you can't use `makeSafe` inside of `makeSafe`.